# Trouble returning swapped integers with functions

Tags: c#, function

I have been asked to "Write a function that swaps two integers(I am not allowed to use arithmetic or Boolean operators for this) and returns the result"
Unfortunately I have encountered a slight problem. I think I have managed to swap the integers using the XOR algorithm that was suggested but I am not to sure how to return the values. I am quite poor at programming but I hope I have explained this sufficiently enough.

Here is the code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //numberSwap?(int number1, int number2)
}

public int numberSwap(int number1, int number2)
{
    number1 ^= number2;
    number2 ^= number1;//I think this is correct
    number1 ^= number2;

    int result = number1, number2;
    return result;// I think I may have this wrong
}
```

as mentioned above I think that I may have the result assignment and return wrong as well as the called function.

Comment: This sounds like a homework or an interview question. Hint: use another int variable for the swap.

Comment: You need to pass them by reference for this to affect the original values (your function must specify this as well as any places you call the function from).  Alternatively passing in an object with the items should work. Your code is correct, but `int result = number1, number2;` is a syntax error.  Your function returns `int` not `Tuple<int, int>` or anything remotely similar. (To make a tuple: `new Tuple<int, int>(number1, number2)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the number didn't got swapped because you passed the parameter `by value`, you were supposed to pass the parameter `by reference`

---

Passing parameter `By Value` : create a copy of the variable that is sent to the parameter.

Passing parameter `By Reference` modifies the parameter that is passed, and does not create any copy of the variable.

---

Your function logic is correct the only `tiny` thing you missed was passing it `As Reference`

```
public void numberSwap(ref int number1, ref int number2)
{
    number1 ^= number2;
    number2 ^= number1;
    number1 ^= number2;
}
```

and the call to function must be like :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n1 = 5, n2 = 10;
    numberSwap(ref n1, ref n2)
}
```

Comment: That'll work.  Just remember that if `number1` and `number2` references are the same, the XOR operation will result in 0.  So the full proof way is to put an `if (number1 != number2)` around the 3 XORlines.  see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/182043/77075

Comment: yah, that is a drawback but i don't think of any else way of doing it, considering no use of `arithmetic operator`.